# Zip only files starting with mprm* into mprm.zip in python

Tags: python, bash, zip, php-ziparchive

I am trying to write a code to zip files starting with `mprm*` to `mprm.zip` file. My directory has 100 different files with all different types of extension.

As in Bash we can do

```
zip -r pathtofile/mprm path2Destination/mprm*
```

is there something in python that can achieve same?

Thanks!

Comment: There's a `zipfile` module in python and lots of examples on how to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

(worked on python34)

```
import glob
from zipfile import ZipFile, ZIP_DEFLATED

files = glob.glob('mprm*') #find your stuff
z = ZipFile('mprm.zip', mode='w', compression=ZIP_DEFLATED) #change if needed
for f in files:
    z.write(f, f)
print ('done')
```

Answer (score 1):

'

You have a couple of ways in Python to get a list of files. The easiest is probably to use the 'glob' module, like this:

```
import glob
filelist = glob.glob('/home/tryeverylanguage/mprm*')
```

For details on glob, start an interactive Python session by typing 'python' at the command prompt and then typing `import glob`, then `help(glob)`

To get the files you list into a zip file, you'll probably want to use the 'zipfile' module. For details on this module, in your Python interactive session type `import zipfile` and then `help(zipfile)`

By the way, don't confuse the Python built-in 'zip' function with the command to create zip files -- it's completely unrelated.

Hopefully, this will be enough to get you started. Have fun with Python!